# TableView in QT5 doesn't show MYSQL Data, just empty rows are shown

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, tableview, qt5

I am showing you my problem by showing a screen shot. This seems easier to me.[image]

My Table is empty in my program, but it has the right amount of columns and if I add more columns in my sql workbench it will get more rows, but nothing is displayed in them.
Here is my Source Code:

```
void adminUserData::on_pushButton_Load_clicked()
{
    // This Object is for connecting to my Database (it works).
    Datenbank db;
    db.connData();

    QSqlQueryModel* model = new QSqlQueryModel();

    QSqlQuery* qry = new QSqlQuery(db.db);

    qry->prepare("SELECT * FROM worker");

    qry->exec();
    model->setQuery(*qry);

    ui->tableView->setModel(modal);

    qDebug() << model->rowCount();
    db.discData();
}
```

I have no clue whats wrong. Here is a screen shot of my database in the workbench:
[image]
Thank you guys for helping me.
best regards

Comment: You're also leaking both the model and the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't "ui->tableView->setModel(modal);" be "ui->tableView->setModel(mod**e**l);"?

Comment: if you have some question to the question earn some reputation and comment / vote - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 2):

I think (since we don't have `Datenbank` source code) the problem is in declaring `Datenbank db;` on the stack, when the function exist, database is closed leading to invalidating your query and model, to solve the issue, either declare it on the heap using `new` or use it as a member of your class.

Comment: ty the disconecting was the problem