# Using QSqlQuery and table view

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, sqlite, pyqt5

I am trying add basic search functionality to my project so I created a search bar and a search button, when said button is clicked I want to query a database and display the results on a table view widget.

However I still don't quite understand how to add data to the table, I tried creating a QsqlQuery and using the setQuery method of the table widget, but when I click the search button nothing happens.
What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code.

```
def searchEvent(self):
  '''
  Send appropriate search query and display results on the tableView
  '''
  # Connect to the database
  db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
  db.setDatabaseName("data.sqlite3")
  db.open()

  # Prepare query
  query = QtSql.QSqlQuery(db)
  query.prepare("SELECT * FROM SetInfo_view WHERE Name LIKE(?)")
  query.bindValue(0, self.searchLineEdit.text())

  # Prepare table model
  tableModel = QtSql.QSqlQueryModel()
  tableModel.setQuery(query)
  self.tableView.setModel(tableModel)
  self.tableView.show()
  db.close()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the documentation I found out that it is necessary to actually execute the query before adding it as a model to the table view, like so:

```
def searchEvent(self):
  '''
  Send appropriate search query and display results on the tableView
  '''
  # Connect to the database
  db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
  db.setDatabaseName("data.sqlite3")
  db.open()

  # Prepare query
  query = QtSql.QSqlQuery(db)
  query.prepare("SELECT * FROM SetInfo_view WHERE Name LIKE(?)")
  query.bindValue(0, self.searchLineEdit.text())
  query.exec_()

  # Prepare table model
  tableModel = QtSql.QSqlQueryModel()
  tableModel.setQuery(query)
  self.tableView.setModel(tableModel)
  self.tableView.show()
  db.close()
```

Source: [TableView in QT5 doesn't show MYSQL Data, just empty rows are shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30289813/tableview-in-qt5-doesnt-show-mysql-data-just-empty-rows-are-shown)